# WiFi network programming in android

Tags: java, android, network-programming

i want to program a server/client app in android.
i have one server class on my pc and client on my android phone.
all permissions are ok.
Here is client:

```
        try {
        mysocket = new Socket("My PC IP Address", 4444);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {...
    } catch (IOException e) {...
    }
```

here is server:

```
        try {
        myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {...
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection Established.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

I uses "Connectify" program on my pc to have an (virtual)access point such that my phone connect to that.
But when I try to connect to server in my android app, it hangs and then throws Timed-out exception.

Comment: Make sure you are trying to connect to the PC's "connectify" IP address, which is likely different from its normal one.

Comment: From the connectify configuration console.  Or from something like ifconfig (linux) or ipconfig /all (windows).  Look for an additional interface that's only present when connectify is running.  If you can get the phone's wifi address, you want the one for the pc that is on the same subnet as the phone, not the one that talks to the upstream cable modem or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't look bad.

Are you certain Connectify is working well? 
You shoud try running both the server and the client you have built on your PC, using two different processes (as an example the server as a standalone and the client in the Android Emulator).

If it works properly from localhost to localhost:4444, the the connection is the cause of the problem, not your code. And otherwise, you will easily find the bug in your code.